# http response is not allowed or not handled in python using scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

even though i'm passing headers like below, i'm getting 416 error: http is not handled or not allowed.

```
headers = {'Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
                       'Accept-Encoding':'gzip, deflate, br,sdch',
                       'Accept-Language':'en-US,en;q=0.8',
                       'AlexaToolbar-ALX_NS_PH':'AlexaToolbar/alx-4.0.1',
                       'Cache-Control':'max-age=0',
                       'Connection':'keep-alive',
                       'Host':'www.links.com',
                       'Referer':'https://www.links.com/',
                       'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests':'1',
                       'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36'}
```

Comment: Show some relevant code please

Answer (score 0):

Try limiting the headers to below and see if it helps

```
headers = {
          'Accept-Language':'en-US,en;q=0.8',
          'Cache-Control':'max-age=0',
          'Host':'www.mdlinx.com',
          'Referer':'https://www.mdlinx.com/',
          'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36'}
```

Basically your site is throwing 416 and of course scrapy won't handle that. So you need to workout which headers are causing the issue. Best thing is to use chrome dev tools, copy the request as curl and see if that works. Also this may be related to no cookies being there.

You need to figure what works and what doesn't and then work this out

**Edit-1**

[image: Copy As curl]

Comment: i did'nt get u on this....Best thing is to use chrome dev tools, copy the request as curl and see if that works. Also this may be related to no cookies being there.

You need to figure what works and what doesn't and then work this out